# mvc4 global error handling modular architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I asked this before, however with no code, here is the scenario: I have a basic mvc app, which includes a global.asax, ErrorController.cs, and Error.cshtml. What I want to achieve is to have this as a center point for all error handling in my other mvc apps. But seems to have hit the wall, so any feedback/help appreciated. This handler application is called from another mvc app., and on calling the last line of code: (IController).Execute() causes the 'view not found'. What I think is happening the call is passed back to the callee app and since there is no view by that name, hence the error. So, what I want is for the handler app to use its own error view. I do not know if that's possible at all? 
Here is the code in global.asax

```
protected virtual void OnApplicationError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpApplicationContext = ((HttpApplication) sender).Context;
    var currentController = string.Empty;
    var currentAction = string.Empty;
    var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpApplicationContext));

    if (currentRouteData != null)
    {
        if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(currentRouteData.Values["controller"])))
        {
            currentController = Convert.ToString(currentRouteData.Values["controller"]);
        }
        if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(currentRouteData.Values["action"])))
        {
            currentAction = Convert.ToString(currentRouteData.Values["action"]);
        }
    }

    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var action = "Error";
    var errorController = new ErrorController();

    httpApplicationContext.ClearError();
    httpApplicationContext.Response.Clear();
    httpApplicationContext.Response.StatusCode = ex is HttpException ? ( (HttpException)ex ).GetHttpCode() : 500;
    httpApplicationContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    if (httpApplicationContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
    {
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        routeData.Values["action"] = action;
        errorController.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController, currentAction);
        ((IController)errorController).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpApplicationContext), routeData));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right:  after a lot googling and reading, I managed to make this work:
Basically created another class library and added a new class inheriting from VirtualPathProvider based this link http://www.danielroot.info/2013/07/reuse-mvc-views-using-virtual-path.html.  Then added a reference to this library from MVC app., all seems to be working fine.